# Setting up for Zend Framework htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework

That is my project dir:

```
/webroot
/myproject
    index.php
    /application
    /config
    /library
    /public
        /css
        /img
        /js
        index.php
        .htaccess
```

That is my code in /myproject/index.php

```
<?php include 'public/index.php';
```

Code in .htaccess file:

```
#SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|html|pps)$ index.php [NC,L]

order allow,deny
allow from all
```

Problem is that I can't load css,img or js files from css,img,js directories.

```
The requested URL /css/style.css was not found on this server.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a htaccess problem. Your DOCUMENT_ROOT should point at your public folder, but it looks like it's currently pointing at your myproject folder (this is a big security hole). You'll probably find that `/myproject/css/style.css` will work fine. You should update your virtual host settings to fix this.

Comment: How to edit DOCUMENT_ROOT? Can I use only htaccess file without virtual host?